# UJS - how to change a link from POST to DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I have a link that "POST"s using AJAX. The second time you click it, it needs to delete what it just created.

I've tried `$(this).attr("data-method", "delete")` on a link that "posts", but it doesn't delete. Is my only solution to generate a hidden delete link, and use jquery to switch it out?

Comment: can you put your code?

Comment: Have your tried `$(this).data('method', 'delete')`? Should work https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L170

Answer (score 0):

I'd try @papirtiger's solution (see comment above) but on principle I'd prefer to add a second (hidden / swapped-out) link, rather than change the method of the first link. Your solution feels a bit too "clever" -- we all know Ruby and Rails make it deadly easy for us to be "clever" and it gets easy to do magical things that create more confusion for future developers (or a future you) than they're worth.

Yes, adding second link is wordier. More HTML markup, more JS. But I imagine this wordier solution leaves you with fewer *novel techniques* being employed within the same app, and hence fewer surprises, and that has its own value.